# Setting Admin time availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a booking system. I have the user booking system and the admin (devise) user.

The admin will need to be able to set their time availability in the admin page which will then be available on the user form.

Currently I was thinking about putting a start_datetime and end_datetime in the admin.rb model but this doesn't account for days of the week.

My idea is to have a checkbox for each day and then a time start and time end.

Any suggestions on how I'd restrict the dates shown in the form for booking.rb to the times set by the admin.

Code is very basic at the moment but let me know if you would like anything from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's Time class has lots of options for datetime validation. You could do something like

```
if user_submitted_time.saturday? || user_submitted_time.sunday? ...
```

This would work for validation. You could just black out the dates somehow in the view.

Check out the documentation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html) for more possibilities.

You could add a helper for your view to use that checks whether or not a date is available. Then disable the field using javascript if it is already booked.

Helper:

```
def is_booked(appt)
  appointment = Appointment.find_by_id(appt)
  if appointment.start_time?
  true
end
```

View:

```
<% @appointments.each do |appt| %>
   <% if appt.is_booked(appt.id) %>
   <%= appt.date, class: "booked" %>
   <% else %>
   <%= appt.date, class: "open" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then use CSS or Javascript to disable/hide the dates that are booked. All this can be refactored to be cleaner (you could use the helper to return the class in the view), but this is this should give you the general idea.

Comment: I understand the validation but I want the user not even to be able to select a time in the booking if the admin doesn't have that in available times. I was thinking about storing days, start_time & end_time. Who thought time could get so confusing.

Comment: Edited original answer. It may take a bit of tweaking, but should get you close. Yeah, datetime can be a real pain. Either way, you should check out the link above for some of the methods available from Ruby's Time class. It might come in handy later on.

Comment: Ok but how do I store the data in the admin model. User can check available from: & available to: and how would I store the days of the week ie; :mon, :tue, :wed, :thu, :fri

Comment: You don't. Datetime is datetime as far as the database is concerned. Just use the methods at the documentation above to simplify the data at the view layer.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. My admin needs to set the date he is available in the form on the admin page. I've set a 5 boolean structures in the admin model along with a start and end time. The admin can then set this in a checkbox and drop down and I'll use a helper like to suggested to compare against the admin model.

Comment: Are you using something like jQuery datepicker?